# Using the Limit Comparison Test on $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2} {n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

is this right ?
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2} {n!}
$$
i need to use quotient criterion

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{n^2}{n!}}{ \frac{1}{n!}} =    \lim_{n\to\infty} {\frac{n^2}{n!}} { \frac{n!}{1}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} {n^2} = \infty
$$

so $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{n^2}{n!}}{ \frac{1}{n!}} $$ equals $\infty$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1} {n!} $$ is divergent  it means that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2} {n!}$$ is divergent

Comment: Use the ratio test !!

Comment: It need to be Limit comparison test. That is the task.

Comment: $\sum {1 \over n!}$ is **not** divergent.

Comment: $\frac{1}{n!}$ fades very quickly, faster than $\frac{1}{n^2}$, so $\sum \frac{1}{n!}$ is convergent.

Answer (score 3):

Can you show that $\dfrac{n^2}{n!}<\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ for sufficiently large $n$?

Then use the monotonic property of the sum from that $n$ onwards. The other $n$'s less than that particular $n$ contribute only to a finite sum.

EDIT: Since the question used the words "Limit Comparison", consider comparing with $\dfrac{1}{(n-2)!}$.

Notice that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{n^2}{n!}}{\dfrac{1}{(n-2)!}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n}{n-1}=1$$

Note that $\dfrac{1}{n!}<\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ for all $n>3$. Thus $\sum_{n=3}^\infty\dfrac{1}{(n-2)!}$ converges. Hence $\sum_{n=3}^\infty \dfrac{n^2}{n!}$ converges, and hence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{n^2}{n!}$ converges.

Comment: I see.. that works.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Another straightforward use of the limit test can be done in small pieces:

- Show that $n^2\lt 4\cdot(n-1)^2$ for sufficiently large $n$ (hint: this is equivalent to $n\lt 2(n-1)$ for positive $n$; you should be able to solve that inequality algebraically)
- This then gives $\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty \frac{n^2}{n!}\lt 4\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty \frac{(n-1)^2}{n!}$.
- Now, $\frac{(n-1)^2}{n!}=\frac{(n-1)^2}{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)!}\lt\frac{(n-1)^2}{(n-1)\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)!}=?$

Can you fill in the rest of the details from here?

(You should also be able to transform this into a more direct use of the limit comparison test proper — the key concept is to shift the series to get rid of that quadratic term up top)

Answer (score 0):

I propose a simpler, direct approach:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}=&\,\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n\times n}{n\times(n-1)!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n-1)!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n-1+1}{(n-1)!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n-1}{(n-1)!}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\\
=&\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=\underbrace{\frac{0}{0!}}_{=0}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\\
=&\,\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=2e.
\end{align*}

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't work!

In the Limit Comparison Test, you need
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}
$$
to be a positive real number (and not infinity) when comparing $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$.

Consider the example where
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{n} \quad\text{and}\quad b_n = \frac{1}{n^2}.
$$
Here $\sum a_n$ is divergent and $\sum b_n$ is convergent, but
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \infty.
$$

I don't know how you would use the Limit Comparison Test here. I see now that Landon does know. So you should see his answer!

As a sidenote, note that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}
$$
is convergent and not divergent.

Comment: Can i say if $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {an}{bn} = \infty  $$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty} bn $$ is divergent thatn $$ \lim_{x\to\infty} an $$ is laso divergent  ???

Comment: @Mango: No that doesn't work. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test. The value of the limit has to be a number $0< c < \infty$.

Comment: any suggestion for $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} bn$$  
if i will take $$ \sum_{n\to\infty} bn = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} $$ ??

Comment: @Mango: I don't see how this can be a Limit Comparison Test. This is a nice Comparison Test (as Landon suggests) or a Ratio Test. Are you sure you have to use the Limit Comparison Test?

Comment: @Mango Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Whether you want to call it limit comparison or not, @Mango's proposed test is correct.  If $\sum b_n$ is a divergent series with positive terms and $\sum a_n$ is another positive series such that $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \rightarrow \infty$ then $\sum a_n$ diverges.  The proof is straightforward, eventually $a_n > M b_n$ and thus the tail of $\sum a_n$ exceeds that of $\sum b_n$.

Comment: @JasonKnapp: Things have names for a reason. The OP mentions the Limit Comparison Test in the title and in a comment. The Limit Comparison Test requires that the limit be a positive number and not infinity. That's it. There are, of course, other tests that one can use here.

Comment: Hmmm. Why the down vote?